# Continuously monitoring text file and sending updates to the webpage thru a websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, server, push

okay, so I have a file *'xyz.txt'* in my server folder and i need to push it thru a websocket continuously so that whenever *xyz.txt* is updated on the server, the webpage automatically displays the updated content of the *.txt* file.
I was thinking of moving the *txt* data to a variable that can be sent over the *ws.send()*.. but i havent been able to get the txt data into the var either.

also, i dont want to use AJAX as the txt file in practice will be updated in a few milliseconds.
Any help on this will be great!! thank you! :)

Comment: Right, what have you tried/looked into?

Comment: So i tried a few demos on websockets but none of them actually show how to get the info from a txt file on the server to be displayed on the webpage.
I tried [danielnill](http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/) tutorial and it displays the date and time with updates every 1000ms, but i couldnt figure out how i can get all that info from a text file.

Comment: I tried this: 
 'var path ="sendme.txt";   
         console.log("Sending text: " + path);
         fs.exists(path, function(result) {
              var data = '{ "type":"text", "path":"' + path + '"}';
             console.log(path)
              ws.send(data); '
if i can get the text data into a var, im sure i can manage to send it thru the WS and manage a time interval for the automatic updates.
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Start a webocket connection in the web page. When a message arrives the onmessage event fires which writes the data to the div displaying the text. (simplified hack of functioning code - untested):

```
    var socket;
    function pxstart() {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function wsinit() {
            if (!("WebSocket" in window)) {
                alert("Your browser doesn't support latest Websockets");
                return;
            }
            var wsUrl = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8001/';
            var protocol = 'Px';
            socket = new WebSocket(wsUrl, protocol);
            socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
            var js = JSON.parse(evt.data);
            $(DIVNAME).html(js.data);
        };
    }
```

An app on the server monitors the txt file. When it detects a change in the text file it sends the text to the websocket server Send method, which immediately sends it to the connected browser via the websocket protocol.

Re the app: If you want to use js maybe someone with more experience in that language can step in and suggest code for that part. Suggest start with a very simple test string and build from that.